# Phone in always on usb not shown in my computer

Tags: usb, windows, usb-drivers

When I plug my phone (Galaxy S2, I9100) in an ordinary usb port on a HP Folio laptop it appears in windows explorer and I can browse phone content. But when I plug it in an always on usb the phone does not appear in windows explorer but it is being charged. Is there any extra driver that I need to install or tweak some settings for the phone to appear? Windows did install some drivers the first time I plugged my phone in ordinary usb port.

Windows 7 SP1, 64bit